# How to select with regex this character?

Tags: regex, ip

For the example i have these four ip address:

10.100.0.11; wrong

10.100.1.12; good

10.100.11.4; good

10.100.44.1; wrong

The task has simple rules. In the 3rd place cant be 0, and the 4rd place cant be a solo 1.
I need to select they from an ip table in different routers and i know only this rules.
My solution:

```
^(10.100.[1-9]{1,3}.[023456789]{1,3})$
```

but in this case every number with 1 like 10, 100 etc is missing, so in this way this solution is wrong.

```
^(10.100.[1-9]{1,3}.[1-9]{2,3})$
```

This solve the problem of the single 1, but make another one.

Comment: You need to escape the `.`s, those are special characters in regex. `[023456789]` doesn't allow for a `1` to be present but `12` requires a `1`. The `*` at the end also is invalid, if you want the last number to be optional do `{0,3}` but that seems wrong

Comment: i know [023456789] doesn't allow it. I made a 2nd one in the question, but there can be a solo one in the end.

Comment: Maybe something like `^(10[.]100[.][1-9]{1,3}[.](?:[02-9]|1\d){1,3})` works for you? More examples would help. That would allow `10.100.44.000` is that allowed? Also this allows for numbers greater than 255, and doesnt allow for ipv6.

Comment: probably you have right, the addresses are ipv4 and the 10.100.44.0 is can be an address, but nowhere we use them, but your solution is working for me so thx

Comment: What do you mean by "place"? Character position, or octet?

Comment: tripleee i thinked about octet, just i didn't know their name

Comment: `^10\.100\.(?!0\.)\d+\.(?!1$)\d{1,3}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/s36lXT/1

Answer (score 1):

From the rules you have given, this regex should work:

```
10\.100\.([123456789]\d*|\d{2,})\.([^1]$|\d{2,})
```

it also matches 3rd position number containing a 0 but not in the first place.
so `10.100.10.4` will match as well as `10.100.02.4`

I don't know if it's the intended behavior since I'm not familiar with ip adress.

The last part `\.([^1]$|\d{2,})` reads like this:

"after the 3rd dot is either

- a character which is not 1 followed by the end of the line
- or two or more digits"

If you want to avoid malformed string containing non-digit character like `10.100.12.a` to be match you should replace `[^1]` by `[023456789]` or lazier (and therefore better ;) by `[02-9]`

I use https://regex101.com to debug regex. It's just awesome.
Here is [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/LtMRKg/1) if you want to play with it

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
^10\.100\.[1-9]{1,3}\.(?:[02-9]|\d{2,3})$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `10\.100\.` Match `10.100.` (note to escape the dot to match it literally)
- `[1-9]{1,3}` Match 3 times a digit 1-9
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[02-9]` Match a digit 0 or 2-9
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{2,3}` Match 2 or 3 digits 0-9
- `)` Close the group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MJWJwx/1)

Comment: I appreciate it! But :D i can't escape nothing because i can't use \ character. #mikrotik and  the ? also a non usable character. In the mikrotik webpage they said the mikrotik scripts are compatibled with regex, but in this case...

Comment: @GáborFábos Try double escaping the backslashes `^10\\.100\\.[1-9]{1,3}\\.(?:[02-9]|\\d{2,3})$`

Comment: Ah yes, after i wrote my comment i got that idea too. In this way it doesn't get error. But gives back an empty value as variable. But probably it will be my fault somehow